# Pop first element in a list using a macro

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have the following code

```
(defmacro popm(l)
`(prog1 (car ,l)
    (setf ,l (cdr ,l))))
```

which is supposed to pop the first element out of the list. However, I don't know how to call the macro. I tried using `(popm (2 3 4))` but I get the error "EVAL: 2 is not a function name; try using a symbol instead". Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to debug macros is to use [`macroexpand-1`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mexp_.htm):

```lisp
(macroexpand-1 '(popm (1 2 3)))
(PROG1 (CAR (1 2 3)) (SETF (1 2 3) (CDR (1 2 3))))
```

Now it should be clear why your macro does not work: it cannot be used with constant objects.

It does work with variables though:

```lisp
(defparameter a '(1 2 3))
(popm a)
==> 1
a
==> (2 3)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with constant objects, or does it just have to be called with a variable?

Comment: no, you cannot modify constants!

Comment: right, I should've guessed from the word "Constant" :P. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don't modify literals.

Secondly, as a macro which pops a value from a list held in a variable (or, more generally a place), your macro is unsafe, because it evaluates its argument more than once.  Instead it should be this:

```
(defmacro popm (place)
  (let ((<v> (make-symbol "V")))
    `(let ((,<v> ,place))               ;evaluate PLACE only once
       (prog1 (car ,<v>)
         (setf ,place (cdr ,<v>))))))
```

Finally if what you want to do is mutate list structure (but not literals!) you can do that, and you don't need a macro.  Here is a function which almost does that:

```
(defun pop-list (l)
  ;; BROKEN
  (prog1 (car l)
    (setf (car l) (cadr l)
          (cdr l) (cddr l))))
```

This seems to work:

```
> (let ((l (list 1 2 3))) ;note not a literal!
    (values (pop-list l)
            l))
1
(2 3)
```

So that looks good.  Except it doesn't actually work:

```
> (let ((l (list 1 2 3)))
    (values (pop-list l)
            (pop-list l)
            (pop-list l)
            l))
1
2
3
(nil)
```

It can't work because at the point where the list is a single cons it can't deal with that (this is why `popm` needs to be a macro).  There are two solutions to that: one is to say that, well, after it's popped all the contents, it just returns `nil` all the time.  But then you can't know if the list is empty or not.  So, well, here's another approach:

```
(defun pop-list (l)
  ;; Returns two values: the thing popped, and whether this was the
  ;; last thing.  Popping a broken heart is an error.
  (let ((broken-heart (load-time-value (make-symbol "BROKEN-HEART") t)))
    (cond
     ((eq (car l) broken-heart)
      (error "broken heart"))
     ((null (cdr l))
      (values (prog1 (car l)
                (setf (car l) broken-heart))
              t))
     (t
      (values (prog1 (car l)
                (setf (car l) (cadr l)
                      (cdr l) (cddr l)))
              nil)))))
```

And now

```
> (let ((l (list 1 2 3)))
    (pop-list l))
1
nil

> (let ((l (list 1 2 3)))
    (pop-list l)
    (pop-list l)
    (pop-list l))
3
t

> (let ((l (list 1 2 3)))
    (pop-list l)
    (pop-list l)
    (pop-list l)
    (pop-list l))

Error: broken heart
```